# How to setup an SVN repository for my code?

Tags: svn

How can I set up a SVN repository where I can commit code from my Windows machine and have it available to be checked out on Mac? I tried setting up a SVN server with VisualSVN which works well on the same machine that the server is running but I can't access the code from a different computer. How can I create this setup?

Answer (score 0):

You need a SVN host to store you repository in web accessible location. Try [RiouxSVN](https://riouxsvn.com/) which is a free hosting service that you can use to get started.